# Change Text Color, BG Color etc in the entire application

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

Is it possible to change text color/size, bg colors, forms ratios all in one shot? What I am tryin gto accomplish is accommodating people with disabilities who might want to use a high contrast theme in the app so they can see text better. Increase font size and so on...

For example:

```
testForm->ScaleBy(90,100);
```

This scales down the form by 10%.

I can change all this stuff on each individual form... But is there a way to do it in a settings form that can carry the change to the entire application?

I am using C++ Builder 6 and just started playing with C++ Builder - Berlin. Or Rad Studio Berlin Edition (I think this is their latest one).

Thank you!

Comment: There is no single setting to do this process-wide.  But you can loop through the global `TScreen::Forms[]` list, updating each active Form as needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's exactly what I did... Thanks to your email :-)